# Gradient descent returning nan

Tags: c, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I need to write a function to get a curve fit of a dataset. The code below is what I have. It attempts to use gradient descent to find polynomial coefficients which best fit the data.

```
//solves for y using the form y = a + bx + cx^2 ...
double calc_polynomial(int degree, double x, double* coeffs) {
    double y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        y += coeffs[i] * pow(x, i);

    return y;
}

//find polynomial fit
//returns an array of coefficients degree + 1 long
double* poly_fit(double* x, double* y, int count, int degree, double learningRate, int iterations) {
    double* coeffs = malloc(sizeof(double) * (degree + 1));
    double* sums = malloc(sizeof(double) * (degree + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
        coeffs[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        //reset sums each iteration
        for (int j = 0; j <= degree; j++)
            sums[j] = 0;

        //update weights
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            double error = calc_polynomial(degree, x[j], coeffs) - y[j];

            //update sums
            for (int k = 0; k <= degree; k++)
                sums[k] += error * pow(x[j], k);
        }

        //subtract sums
        for (int j = 0; j <= degree; j++)
            coeffs[j] -= sums[j] * learningRate;
    }

    free(sums);

    return coeffs;
}
```

And my testing code:

```
double x[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double y[] = { 5, 3, 2, 3, 5 };
int size = sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x);

int degree = 1;
double* coeffs = poly_fit(x, y, size, degree, 0.01, 1000);

for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
    printf("%lf\n", coeffs[i]);
```

The code above works when degree = 1, but anything higher causes the coefficients to come back as nan.

I've also tried replacing

```
coeffs[j] -= sums[j] * learningRate;
```

with

```
coeffs[j] -= (1/count) * sums[j] * learningRate;
```

but then I get back 0s instead of nan.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `1/count` is *integer division*, whose result is truncated.

Comment: Ah that was the problem... I feel dumb now

Comment: I tried `degree = 2, iteration = 10` and got results other than `nan` (values around a few thousands) Adding one to `iteration` seems making magnitude of the results larger by about 3 times after that.

Comment: Consider avoiding the repeated calls to `pow` implementing [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to evaluate the polynomial and something similar for the error sum.

Comment: Note: using `printf("%le\n", coeffs[i]);` is more informative than `printf("%lf\n", coeffs[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried `degree = 2, iteration = 10` and got results other than `nan` (values around a few thousands) Adding one to `iteration` seems making magnitude of the results larger by about 3 times after that.

From this observation, I guessed that the results are being multiplied by `count`.

In the expression

```
coeffs[j] -= (1/count) * sums[j] * learningRate;
```

Both of `1` and `count` are integers, so *integer division* is done in `1/count` and it will become zero if `count` is larger than 1.

Instead of that, you can divide the result of multiplication by `count`.

```
coeffs[j] -= sums[j] * learningRate / count;
```

Another way is using `1.0` (`double` value) instead of `1`.

```
coeffs[j] -= (1.0/count) * sums[j] * learningRate;
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside:

A candidate `NAN` source is adding opposite signed values where one is an infinity.  Given OP is using `pow(x, k)`, which grows rapidly, using other techniques help.

Consider a chained multiplication rather than `pow()`.  The result is usually more numerically stable.  `calc_polynomial()` for example:

```
double calc_polynomial(int degree, double x, double* coeffs) {
  double y = 0;
  // for (int i = 0; i <= degree; i++)
  for (int i = degree; i >= 0; i--)
    //y += coeffs[i] * pow(x, i);
    y = y*x + coeffs[i];
  }
  return y;
}
```

Similar code could be used for the `main()` body.